Need to send emails programmatically using Gmail API
I have configured my Gmail client to use my official company domain using Google's SMTP to send emails manually. This works like a charm and have been using this for more than 1 year.
Now I need to send emails programmatically as well, hence trying to make GmailAPI work on the same.
I have been able to create drafts, extract labels, and send the drafts and messages directly without creating the draft too. However, the sending part is where I'm facing some issues, the email is being shown as sent in Gmail Client but not being actually delivered to the Receiver's Inbox (or spam folder)
Hunch 1: The email are being sent but are marked as phishy hence getting discarded at receiver's inbox.
Hunch 2: The Gmail API is not actually sending the email, just putting it in the Sent folder, like adding a tag 'SENT' to the email.
Hunch 3: Prolly need to publish the app (right now in testing mode), to be able to actually send the email.
Seems like Hunch 1 is most likely because when I compared the email original code in when sending emails manually, programmatically, I noticed this header being added to the email.
Received: from 814388093175 named unknown by  with HTTPREST; Thu, 27 Jun 2024 01:16:36 -0400gmailapi.google.com

Which most likely says that the source is unknown, so the receiver's inbox ditches this email and never shows it in the inbox.
If that is the case, what is the solution?
Code for reproducing:
import base64
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import html2text
import os    
from google.cloud import translate
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

def create_general_message(username, to_email, from_email):
  message = EmailMessage()
  message['Subject'] = f'Namaste {username}'
  message['From'] = from_email
  message['To'] = to_email
  message.set_content('Menu')
  with open('Email Code.html', 'r') as file:
    html = file.read()
    text = html2text.html2text(html)
  print(message)

  # according to RFC2046 the last part is preferred
  # message.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html'))

  return {"raw": base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()}


def main():
  creds = None
  SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic", "https://mail.google.com/"]

  if os.path.exists("token.json"):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
  if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
      creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
      flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
          "credentials.json", SCOPES
      )
      creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open("token.json", "w") as token:
      token.write(creds.to_json())

  try:
    # Call the Gmail API
    service = build("gmail", "v1", credentials=creds)
    service.users()
    create_message = create_general_message('Devansh Garg', 'devstep11@gmali.com', 'info@mycompanydomain.in')
    send_message = (
      service.users()
      .messages()
      .send(userId="me", body=create_message)
      .execute()
    )
    print(f'Message Id: {send_message["id"]}')
    print(create_message)
    service.close()
  except HttpError as error:
    print(f"An error occurred: {error}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()


A Received: header is entirely informational; the presence or absence of this information should play absolutely no role in your scenario. (But it looks vaguely like you didn't copy/paste it correctly.)

You have a lot of useless imports. Modern email code needs little more than the EmailMessage import, and in particular, should generally stay away from the legacy MIMEText et al. classes.

You generate html and text but then fail to use them for anything; you are simply sending Menu. Gmail tends to dislike when you repeatedly send the same short message, so I'm guessing that's what happened here.

The Python email examples documentation has good succinct code for creating a simple multipart/alternative message with text/plain and text/html parts.
